# How do I remove all comments in a Mathematica notebook?

Tags: notebooks, comment

Is there an option to delete every comment enclosed within `(*  *)`s for a whole notebook? Or is it possible to do it with some string processing?

Comment: Converting a cell to `StandardForm` eliminates comments in the cell. Select all Input cells in the notebook by option-clicking (on a Mac, I don't know the Windows keyboard equivalent) on the cell bracket of any Input cell, and use Cell > Convert To > StandardForm (shift-command-N) to remove comments in the whole notebook. Be aware that reformatting a cell will also eliminate any manual formatting, such as extra carriage returns you may have put in to improve readability of your code, so use with caution.

Comment: Do you want to leave empty comments, or do you want to remove comments altogether? (The body seems to suggest the former and the title the latter.)

Comment: @Peter Mortensen To remove all comments including  the `(*   *)` pair, not leaving empty comments. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Daniel W selecting the cells and converting to `StandardForm` is a great idea. Thank you.

Comment: @nanjun Kuba’s answer is a better long term solution, which is why I put my answer as a comment. That said, sometimes all you are looking for is a quick set of keystrokes, and I have always liked the “select all cells of this type” trick.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

String processing is not needed, fortunately because you'd have to detect nested string/comment patterns. It is easy with existing box structure though:

```
deleteComments[] := deleteComments @ EvaluationNotebook[]; 

deleteComments[nb_NotebookObject] := (
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook]
; NotebookWrite[nb, DeleteCases[NotebookGet[nb], RowBox[{"(*", ___, "*)"}], Infinity]]
)
```

You can run `deleteComments[]` from your notebook or target any notebook you wish.

Comment: Is it possible to condense your two definitions into a single one using a default argument?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform but then you'd have to have a `HoldAll` attribute to not evaluate `EvaluationNotebook[]` too early. Or some kind of `Unevaluated` shenanigans. So this is the way I write such functions.